# Save/Restore Selection with Rangy in ContentEditable Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, contenteditable, rangy

From the research I've done, it seems like Rangy is the best way to go for saving/restoring selections.  I'm unable to get it to work, however.
I included the core and selectionsaverestore files.
I have a button that when clicks, fires the following:

```
savedSel = rangy.saveSelection();
console.log(savedSel);
```

The log returns:

```
Object
doc: HTMLDocument
rangeInfos: Array[1]
restored: false
win: DOMWindow
__proto__: Object
```

I do not see any marker elements in my contenteditable however, and when I try to restore, nothing happens.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `savedSel.rangeInfos[0]`. From the look of the object returned, I think that might work. Possibly. I've never used Rangy before, so that's just a guess. :)

Comment: Hmm if I apply that to the variable before it's set, it says it's undefined.  Where should I apply it?

Comment: Is there any message in the browser console? Do you have an example page?

Comment: Well as I was making a JSfiddle for it, I solved my problem!  I was using an <a> to fire the save selection.  If I use a <button> it now works!

Answer (score 1):

You need to import two files for it to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./rangy-1.2.3/rangy-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./rangy-1.2.3/rangy-selectionsaverestore.js"></script>
```

Perhaps you only imported the "rangy-core.js" ?